# Is there a way to automatically avoid duplicate data insertion in SpringBoot with JPARepository and Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

so my AppUser entity is like this :

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class AppUser {
   // public enum Roles {ADMIN,COLLABORATOR,PROJECT_MANAGER,MANAGER,ACCOUNTANT}
    //TODO : add default values for fields that should not be null?
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String first_name;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @Column(name="cnss")
    private Boolean cnss;
    @ManyToMany(fetch= FetchType.EAGER) // when we load a user, we load their roles
    private Collection<Role> roles= new ArrayList<>();

}
```

in my main app i ran this code:

```
usserService.saveUser(new AppUser(null,"John Doe","Tom","1234",null,new ArrayList<>()));
            userService.saveUser(new AppUser(null,"Michael","Michael","xyz",true,new ArrayList<>()));
            userService.saveUser(new AppUser(null,"Emma Stone","Emma","1234",true,new ArrayList<>()));
            userService.saveUser(new AppUser(null,"Jack Smith","Jack","a1b2c3",false,new ArrayList<>()));
```

which works fine, but when I rerun the app again , the same users get duplicated again with different ids (so I have 8 users in total).

I want to know if there is a way to handle this without explicitly having to write if statements and checking manually of the username already exists or not.

Comment: That is what unique constraints are for.

Comment: If you are inserting with id field then we can use merge option if you are passing null then it will consider it as new record.

Comment: @M.Deinum not really, I'm already using unique constraints but the app crashes and declares that the constraint has be violated. I'm looking for a way to make the app recognize this problem and fix it automatically without crashing or me having to intervene

Comment: Then either check if the user exists or catch the exception (log it and continue).